# how to structure input/formats for batch inference in sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

example provided in the aws documentation , https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform.html, states that the input csv can be structured like a sample below. I noticed for batch jobs in sagemaker, it can accept json as well. how to structure the json, does each record need to in a single line as shown in a csv example or can it be multiline?

```
Record1-Attribute1, Record1-Attribute2, Record1-Attribute3, ..., Record1-AttributeM
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to make use of `JSON Lines` (i.e. each JSON to be on a single line). You can then set BatchStrategy to MultiRecord and `SplitType` to `Line`.
Batch Transform can then fit as many records in a mini-batch within the `MaxPayloadInMB` limit.

Kindly see the [`CreateTransformJob`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTransformJob.html#API_CreateTransformJob_RequestSyntax) API for more information.